# Discord JDA. Дать юзерам Permission на созданном канале

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Я создаю канал с помощью команды + упомнинанием от 1 и более участника сервер и хочу сделать его частным, и чтобы только определенные люди могли в Discord его видеть (включая упомянутых) и сам бот.

Имя чата должно быть как имя первого упомянутого участника.

Не удалось реализовать от 2 и более пользователей отмеченных. Пока получается добавлять статически, но хотелось бы динамически, чтобы сократить число строк, так же, возможно, брать данные из БД.

```java
List<Permission> List = Arrays.asList(Permission.MESSAGE_READ, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE);
String name = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0).getEffectiveName().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");

event.getGuild().getCategoriesByName("Hall", true).get(0)
                .createVoiceChannel(name)
                .addPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getPublicRole(), Collections.emptyList(), List)
                .addPermissionOverride(event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0), List, Collections.emptyList())
                .addPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Admin", true).get(0), List, Collections.emptyList())
                .addPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Moderator", true).get(0), List, Collections.emptyList())
                .addPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getRolesByName("LPA", true).get(0), List, Collections.emptyList())
                .addPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Tech", true).get(0), List, Collections.emptyList())
                .addPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getSelfMember(), List, Collections.emptyList())
                .queue();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ прост, но не очевиден.

Первые две строчки кода оставляем без изменений, а остальное удаляем и вставляем вначале это:

```java
event.getGuild().getCategoriesByName("Hall", true).get(0).createTextChannel(name).queue();
```

Тут мы говорим, что создаем чат в категории `Hall`.Я пытался реализовать отдельно создание чата и отдельное добаление Persmissions, но Persmissions почему-то запускались раньше, поэтому для нужной нам последовательности прибегним к лямбдам.

пишем внутри переменную `channel` и дальше, если действий будет много, открываем фигурные скобки и добавляем следующие данные:

1. Чтобы добавить Permission **одному юзеру/боту** (в нашем случае я использую `@everyone`) просто пишем `channel.putPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getPublicRole()).setDeny(list).queue();`
2. Чтобы прописать упомянутым юзерам/ботам (от 1 и более) - я использую for-loop.
3. Чтобы взять данные из БД, тоже используем for-loop.
4. Чтобы добавить Permissions **нашему боту** - используем строчку `channel.putPermissionOverride(data.getGuild().getSelfMember()).setAllow(list).queue();`

```java
List<Permission> list = Arrays.asList(Permission.MESSAGE_READ, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE);
String name = data.getEvent().getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0).getEffectiveName().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");

event.getGuild().getCategoriesByName("Hall", true).get(0).createTextChannel(name).queue(
                channel -> {
                    channel.putPermissionOverride(event.getGuild().getPublicRole()).setDeny(list).queue();

                    for (Member member : event.getMentionedMembers()) {
                        try {
                            channel.putPermissionOverride(member).setAllow(list).queue();
                        } catch (Exception ignore){}
                    }

                    for(Access access : new Database().getAccess("WHERE access_high=1")){
                        try {
                            channel.putPermissionOverride(data.getGuild().getRolesByName(access.getRole(), true).get(0)).setAllow(list).queue();
                        } catch (Exception ignore){}
                    }
                    channel.putPermissionOverride(data.getGuild().getSelfMember()).setAllow(list).queue();
                }
        );
```